# RESTful URI structures

Tags: rest, path, uri, structure

I have a small question regarding these URL structures.

I have 3 resources persons,credentials and tokens. The relationship is simple. A person has a one-to-one mapping with credentials and credentials has a one-to-many mapping with tokens.

These uri seem restful to me:

- http://somewhere.loc/persons
- http://somewhere.loc/persons/1
- http://somewhere.loc/persons/1/credentials
- http://somewhere.loc/persons/1/credentials/1/tokens
- http://somewhere.loc/persons/1/credentials/1/tokens/1

But since there is a one-to-one mapping between persons and credentials would http://somewhere.loc/persons/1/credential/tokens/1 also be considered restful? Can I omit the id of credentials and make it singular?

I understand that for example /books/pagenumbers would for example return all pagenumbers of all books.

Answer (score 0):

As you said they're three separate resources, maybe I would do it in a different way (but it depends also on how you will manage these resources):

```
/persons/1
/credentials/1
/tokens/1
```

and as you said, in case of getting the credential of a person and then the token, you can omit the id, because they're referencing the same person.

```
/persons/1/credential
/persons/1/credential/token
```

---

**EDIT:**

probably the first thing I said it's not correct, because the id should reference the resource, so the "credentialId" or the "tokenId".
I will leave it anyway, just be careful to it. : )